# How to use tf.estimator.predict for single data item

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction

I'm new to tf.estimator having previously used an older version of tensorflow. Passing in "input_fn" has confused me slightly. I have a DNNClassifier and a numpy array containing a single data item (x) which I'd like to predict a "y" value for.

This is the code I have so far.

```
dnn_clf = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns, n_classes=14, hidden_units=[60, 100], model_dir="/home/Ehoward14/mysite/dnn_model")

predict_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x=scaled_X,
                                                    y=None,
                                                    batch_size=1,
                                                    shuffle=False,
                                                    num_epochs=1)

y_pred = dnn_clf.predict(input_fn=predict_fn)
```

And I'd like to print the single y value like so:

```
    //This will only print one value
    for result in y_pred:
            print(result)
```

scaled_X contains something like:
[[ 1.42857143  0.          0.         16.36363636  0.          1.81818182#012   6.66666667  0.          2.896      20.          0.          0.#012   0.         20.         16.66666667  0.        ]]

This code returns the error:

```
for result in y_pred:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 543, in predict
features, None, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.PREDICT, self.config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1133, in _call_model_fn
     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 385, in _model_fn
    batch_norm=batch_norm)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 179, in _dnn_model_fn
    'Given type: {}'.format(type(features)))
    ValueError: features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. Given type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

Realistically I just need to know if my approach is right or not and if not then any suggestion for improvement would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me:
You should load the exported model that you saved before and feed it with an example**

```
model_estimate_k = tf.saved_model.load('estimatior_k/save_model/1666855778')


def predict(scores: list):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.features.feature["scores"].float_list.value.extend(scores)
    return model_estimate_k.signatures["predict"](examples=tf.constant([example.SerializeToString()]))


print(predict([0.8, 0.9, 0.7]))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).